# Error text input entry and get() entry input

Tags: python, tkinter

have getting confused in getting the value from the Tkinter() Entry Field. I have this kind of code...

```
    def login():
root_login = Tk()
root_login.title("Login")
root_login.geometry("400x400")

label_text_name = Label(root_login, text="Type mail your :")
label_text_name.pack()
label_text_name.place(x=25, y=50)
label_text_token = Label(root_login, text="Type Pasword :" )
label_text_token.pack()
label_text_token.place(x=58, y=150)

input_text_email = Entry(root_login, width=30)
input_text_email.pack()
input_text_email.place(x=150, y=50)

input_text_token = Entry(root_login, width=30)
input_text_token.pack()
input_text_token.place(x=150, y=150)

e1 = Entry(root_login)
e1.pack()
btn_login = Button(root_login,command=after_login, text="Login", height=1, width=10 )
btn_login.pack()
btn_login.place(x=50, y=250)

def after_login():
     var = e1.get()     
     messagebox.showinfo(var1)
```

but i get a error !

var = e1.get()
NameError: name 'e1' is not defined

Comment: `e1` is a local variable in the `login` function (assuming it was indented correctly), you can't access it in the `after_login` function.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
def callback():
print(email.get())

....
..


e = Entry(root, bd=1, textvariable=email, validate="focusout" , validatecommand=callback).grid(column=1, row=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your *after_login* function doesn't know what *e1* is, since it's defined outside of the functions scope. You have to modify your code, maybe by setting the variable as global ( Which can lead to other problems if done incorrectly ) or some other way let *after_login* know what an *e1* is ( by maybe giving it as parameter could solve this? )

Answer (score 0):

Jimpsoni, I have put in a global vatable like this:

```
def login():
root_login = Tk()
root_login.title("Login")
root_login.geometry("400x400")

label_text_name = Label(root_login, text="Type mail your :")
label_text_name.pack()
label_text_name.place(x=25, y=50)
label_text_token = Label(root_login, text="Type Pasword :" )
label_text_token.pack()
label_text_token.place(x=58, y=150)

input_text_email = Entry(root_login, width=30)
input_text_email.pack()
input_text_email.place(x=150, y=50)

input_text_token = Entry(root_login, width=30)
input_text_token.pack()
input_text_token.place(x=150, y=150)

global var1
var1 = input_text_token.get()

btn_login = Button(root_login,command=after_login, text="Login", height=1, width=10 )
btn_login.pack()
btn_login.place(x=50, y=250)

def after_login():
         
     messagebox.showinfo(var1)
```

but now I get this error!

```
    global var1
           ^
```

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: You should update your question instead of posting code update as an answer.  Also this code still has indentation issue. Note also that those `.pack()` are useless because they are override by those following `.place(...)`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).